# How to populate fields in reactjs formik

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to formik and i am trying to populate an edit page where users can edit existing fields with formik. I keep getting **React Hook "useEffect" cannot be called inside a callback. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function react-hooks/rules-of-hooks** error. I used the react useEffect hook to try and get the data from the backend.

```
function Edit({ history, match }) {
const { id } = match.params;
const isAdd = !id;

const initialValues = {

    firstName: '',
    lastName: '',
 
};

const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({

    firstName: Yup.string()
        .required('First Name is required'),
    lastName: Yup.string()
        .required('Last Name is required'),
});


return (
    <Formik initialValues={initialValues} validationSchema={validationSchema} onSubmit={()={}}>
        {({ errors, touched, isSubmitting, setFieldValue }) => {
            useEffect(() => {
                if (!isAdd) {
                    getById(id).then(user => {
                        const fields = ['firstName', 'lastName'];
                        fields.forEach(field => setFieldValue(field, user[field], false));
                    });
                }
            }, []);

            return (
                <Form>
        
                        <div className="form-group col-5">
                            <label>First Name</label>
                            <Field name="firstName" type="text" className={'form-control' + 
                           (errors.firstName && touched.firstName ? ' is-invalid' : '')} />
                            <ErrorMessage name="firstName" component="div" className="invalid- 
                               feedback" />
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group col-5">
                            <label>Last Name</label>
                            <Field name="lastName" type="text" className={'form-control' + 
                              (errors.lastName && touched.lastName ? ' is-invalid' : '')} />
                            <ErrorMessage name="lastName" component="div" className="invalid- 
                               feedback" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
             </Form>
            );
        }}
    </Formik
```

)}
export { Edit };